# Cargar datos no lee los String

Tags: java

Tengo esto metodo para cargar datos por el teclado pero en el toString de la otra clase los String me salen vacios

```
public void altaEmpleado(){


        System.out.println("Introduce el id del empleado :");
            int id=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Introduce el nombre del empleado :");
            String nombre=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduce el apellido 1 del empleado :");    
        sc.next();
            String ape1=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduce el apellido 2 del empleado :"); 
        sc.next();
            String ape2=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduce el salario del empleado :");
            float salario=sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Introduce el oficio del empleado :");
        sc.next();
            String oficio=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Introduce la commission del empleado :");
            float commission=sc.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("Introduce la fecha de alta del empleado :");
        sc.next();
            String fecha_alta=sc.nextLine();

        Empleado em = new Empleado(id,nombre,ape1,ape2,salario,oficio,commission,fecha_alta);

        de.empleado.add(em);
        for(int i = 0 ;  i < de.empleado.size() ; i++)
        System.out.println(de.empleado.get(i));

    }
```

Este es el toString

```
 public String toString() {

        return "El empleado con id : " + id_emp + " con nombre : " + nombre + " " + apell1 + " " + apell2 + " y con salario "
                + "" + salario + " y oficio : " + oficio + " y commission : " + commission;

    }
```

El resultado que me da es este :

El empleado con id : 1 con nombre :    y con salario 1231.0 y oficio :  y commission : 12.0

Answer (score 1):

una forma rapida de resolverlo seria quitarle los    sc.next();    que tienes después de los System.out.println(); y cuando le asignas los valores a los String en vez de usar el método nextLine(); usar el next(); "del Scanner" con eso en el toString() ya te debe de mostrar los datos
tu lo tienes asi:

```
System.out.println("introduce el apellido 1 del empleado");
sc.next();
String ape1 = sc.nextLine();
```

y seria así:

```
System.out.println("introduce el apellido 1 del empleado");
String ape1 = sc.next();
```

Comment: Porque pasa eso?